# Data in Local DB in C# Project is erased after every compilation

Tags: c#, .net, database

so this is my problem:

I have a local DB, its a .mdf file on Visual Studio 2022. My program functions correctly and as intended including the DataBase functions. The problem is that after every compilation, the data stored in the DataBase file is erased, starting from a clean slate, in the past i would run the program and it wouldn't do this unless I made a direct change on to the DataBase structure, like adding a row or a table.

Any Idea of why this could be happening? This is the corrunt "Structure" of my project:

[image]

also this is the configuration on my .mdf File and on my .xsd file:

[image]

Also, when I run the installer version I do not have this problem of course, it works completely as intended.

What I and I need is for these DataBase files to remain with all the data collected during debug sessions, unless some change is made to the DataBase.

Comment: Do you have `context.Database.EnsureDeleted(); context.Database.EnsureCreated();` in your code?

Comment: No, i Do not :(

Comment: Your files get copied to your output directory on every build, so your modifications from the previous run get overwritten.